# DATE function in Oracle

Tags: oracle, function, date

I recently came across sample code like this:

```
select TO_CHAR(DATE '2012-3-1', 'Day Month Year') from dual;
```

I understand the TO_CHAR, but I have never seen that use of DATE before, and can find no documentation relating to it.  Can someone please explain how it works, and/or provide a link to some documentation?

Thanks,
Dan

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You haven't searched far enough :-) Google `Oracle DATE literal` and find:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements003.htm#BABGIGCJ

An extract:

> To specify a DATE value as a literal, you must use the Gregorian
>   calendar. You can specify an ANSI literal, as shown in this example:
>
> ```
> DATE '1998-12-25'
> ```

Comment: +1, but I think it's important to add that it uses the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` by default

Comment: I did search far, I just hadn't thought of including "literal" in my search terms.  Thanks.  As soon at SF lets me, I'll accept your answer.

Comment: @AndyDan: You're probably right. I'm too much into databases that the term "literal" immediately came to my mind. But it's not so obvious, otherwise

Comment: @Ben, that's not correct. The NLS_DATE_FORMAT setting does not affect the `DATE` *literal*, which must always take the form `YYYY-MM-DD`.

Answer (score 1):

here's the doc: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements003.htm#BABGIGCJ